# Runnig Twiiter Cassovary Examples in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, scala, twitter, github

I have imported the *Twitter Cassovary* into **Eclipse** form *Git Hub* but not sure how to run the examples.Please advise as I am new to eclipse as well as scala

Comment: +1 For asking this question. Unfortunately, the Cassovary project could use a better documentation/getting started guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imported the project, opened a benchmark (cassovary-benchmarks/src/main/java/GraphGenerationBenchmarks) and used Run as->Scala application.

You can also do this from the command line. Start sbt in the main project directory, choose subproject cassovary-benchmarks and then use run. You will be asked which benchmark to run.

```
➜  twitter-cassovary git:(master) ✗ ls
README.md            cassovary-examples   project
cassovary-benchmarks cassovary-server     sbt
cassovary-core       lib_managed          target
➜  twitter-cassovary git:(master) ✗ sbt
Loading /Users/szymon/bin/sbt-launch-lib.bash
[info] Loading global plugins from           /Users/szymonmatejczyk/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/szymon/oss/twitter-cassovary/project
[info] Set current project to cassovary (in build file:/Users/szymon/oss/twitter-cassovary/)
> project cassovary-benchmarks
[info] Set current project to cassovary-benchmarks (in build file:/Users/szymon/oss/twitter-cassovary/)
> run
[info] Compiling 12 Scala sources to /Users/szymon/oss/twitter-cassovary/cassovary-core/target/scala-2.11/classes...
[info] Compiling 56 Scala sources to /Users/szymon/oss/twitter-cassovary/cassovary-core/target/scala-2.11/classes...
[info] Compiling 2 Scala sources to /Users/szymon/oss/twitter-cassovary/cassovary-  benchmarks/target/scala-2.11/classes...
[warn] Multiple main classes detected.  Run 'show discoveredMainClasses' to see the list

  Multiple main classes detected, select one to run:

 [1] com.twitter.cassovary.PerformanceBenchmark
 [2] com.twitter.cassovary.SubsetSamplingBenchmarks
 [3] com.twitter.cassovary.GraphGenerationBenchmarks
 [4] com.twitter.cassovary.utils.FastUtilsWrappingBenchmark

Enter number:
```

Comment: Thanks I was able to run it through Command Prompt but I still face issues in Eclipse . I imported the project using [link](http://eclipse.org/egit/) bit while trying to Run as it asks me to Run Configurations (I do not get Run as->Scala application) .Can you advise what I should do for the configuration

Comment: Please, try to import it using sbteclipse plugin.

Comment: Any idea where can I find a tutorial for importing projects using sbteclipse